# Calculating positive and negative numbers for past and future data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying create a data set and finding it difficult to do it manually. I just wanted to know if there is way we can do it automatically in Excel.

[image]

As shown in the above image I need to do it 52 weeks. For e.g. 201703 ; 201704;201705...... 201752.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for your weekdiff could be:

```
=(MIN(DATE(LEFT(A2,4)+1,1,0),DATE(LEFT(A2,4),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(A2,4),1,1),2)+RIGHT(A2,2)*7)-MIN(DATE(LEFT(B2,4)+1,1,0),DATE(LEFT(B2,4),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(B2,4),1,1),2)+RIGHT(B2,2)*7))/7
```

But I am not sure you also want the year-weeks be filled automatically, if so try this sub:

```
Sub tst()
Dim startweek As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, arr(1 To 624, 1 To 3)

startweek = 201701

    For j = 1 To 52
        For i = 1 To 12
        k = k + 1
            If i = 12 Then Exit For
                arr(k, 1) = startweek: arr(k, 3) = 6 - i: arr(k, 2) = startweek - arr(k, 3)
                    If Val(Right(arr(k, 2), 2)) > 52 Then arr(k, 2) = arr(k, 2) - 48
        Next i
    startweek = startweek + 1
    Next j

    Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already identify the pattern of WeekDiff, which always goes from 5 to -5. 
Since you have data for 201701, based on them can generate data from 201702 onwards.
You can use below formulae for CRW, Snapweek and WeekDiff cells once inserting data for 201701. 
Drag till you get preferred result.

Cell#A14    `=IF(A2<>"",A2+1,"")`
Cell#B14    `=IF(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B2,2))<52,IF(B2<>"",B2+1,""),B2+49)`
Cell#C14    `=IF(C2<>"",C2,"")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did mine simultaneously with @Surani and got

In A2

```
=201700+INT((ROW()-2)/11)+1
```

In C2

```
=5-MOD(ROW()-2,11)
```

In B2

```
=IF((MOD(A2,100)-C2)<1,201652-(C2-MOD(A2,100)),IF((MOD(A2,100)-C2)>52,201800+(MOD(A2,100)-C2)-52,201700+MOD(A2,100)-C2))
```

but the other solution looks shorter!